# zsh: show completion group names

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm writing some zsh completions and am stuck on how to have multiple groups of completions.

I added the group name with the `-J` parameter [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Builtin-Commands).

```
compadd -J group1 "$@" completion1 completion2
compadd -J group2 "$@" completion3 completion4
```

Then I added the `zstyle` to my `~/.zshrc` [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles) (heading: `group-name`)

```
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
```

The completions come up fine, but the group names are not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *believe* group-name only applies to the command position (i.e. the first one). Myself, I only use compadd directly for custom completion of command options, in this case, it is the `-x message` that gets used:

Contents of `_foo`:

```
#compdef  foo    
A=( -h --help foo bar baz )
compadd -J group1 -X expl1 -x msg1 -a A
B=( clown-fish hippo )                                                   
compadd -J group2 -X expl2 -x msg2 -a B
```

then somewhere else:

```
function foo { echo $* }
compdef _foo foo
```

When I run this completion, I get the options grouped by message.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the group names appeared only after adding:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
```